# Latest react-redux and redux-form cause significant performance issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Upgraded to latest versions (as of today):

```
react-redux: 5.0.7 --> 7.2.1
redux-form: 7.4.2 --> 8.3.6
```

After doing so, a significant loss in performance was noticed when sorting, typing inside fields etc. and eventually the following error shows which breaks the app:

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
> repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
> componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
> prevent infinite loops.
>
> The above error occurred in the <Form(Connect(WrapperComponent))>
> component:...

The only thing which was done was the upgrade, the code remained the same.

Here is a snippet of the withForm HOC and connect (defined as per the docs)

```
 const withForm = reduxForm({
   form: 'form-name',
   initialValues: {
     ...initVals
   },
   onSubmit,
   validate,
   shouldError: () => true
 });

 export default compose(
   connect,
   withForm,
   withStyles(styles)
 )(MyComponent);
```

Does anyone have a clue what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to the latest form (see question) for some reason redux-form wasn't happy on how I explicitly reset properties on the form.

```
const connectForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'form-name',
  validate: values => {
    const errors = {};
    if (values.middle) {
      values.first = '';
    } else {
      values.second = ''
      values.third = '';
    }
  },
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  initialValues: {
    ...initValues
  }
});
```

Hence produced a stackoverflow.

Used reset built in function to reset those

```
import {reset} from 'redux-form';

...

dispatch(reset('myForm'));  // requires form name
```